# Grouped bar chart with time duration on y axis in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have data like,

```
column1 <- c(rep("ab", 3), rep("cd", 3), rep("ef", 3))
column2 <- gl(3, 1, 9, labels=c("abc", "def", "ghi"))
column3 <- c("10:10:00", "01:15:10", "00:00:20", "01:20:40", "05:20:55", "10:00:00", "02:00:30", "03:23:55", "10:01:40")
```

I need to plot grouped bar chart for this data using ggplot. I tried below rscript.

```
d <- data.frame(column1=column1, column2=column2, column3=column3)

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=column1, y=column3, fill=column2)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(),stat="identity")
```

It gives plot like,

[image]

Which looks wrong because of below problems,

1. Order of columns is consistent
2. Time on Y-axis is not consistent. (Range is wrong).

but if I try below data,

```
column1 <- c(rep("ab", 3), rep("cd", 3), rep("ef", 3))
column2 <- gl(3, 1, 9, labels=c("abc", "def", "ghi"))
column3 <- c(10, 15, 20, 80, 95, 10, 30, 55, 80)

d <- data.frame(column1=column1, column2=column2, column3=column3)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x=column1, y=column3, fill=column2)) + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(),stat="identity")
```

It produces graph like,

[image]

Which looks perfect. 
Problem I see here is that it works with integers but not with time data type. I tried to play with it but couldn't get success. Can anyone help me create correct graph or please suggest if some other approach is needed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it sufficient to have the Y-axis in minutes, or do you want hours + minutes? i.e. do you want "01:20:00" instead of "80"?

Comment: Also, does column3 contain specific times or durations?

Comment: Your times are just strings/factors, not actual times. You need to use a time class to evaluate them proportionally, e.g. `chron::times` or one of the `lubridate` ones (maybe `duration`; `interval` is between two datetimes).

Comment: We have to assume you googled "ggplot time duration". Can you please elaborate why the two first hits weren't helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution converts assumes column3 is a duration and converts it to a Duration class as @alistaire suggests. It also may take some tinkering to get the labels to show up at regular intervals, but that should be easy.

```
library(ggplot2)

column1 <- c(rep("ab", 3), rep("cd", 3), rep("ef", 3))
column2 <- gl(3, 1, 9, labels=c("abc", "def", "ghi"))
column3 <- c("10:10:00", "01:15:10", "00:00:20", "01:20:40", "05:20:55", 
    "10:00:00", "02:00:30", "03:23:55", "10:01:40")

d <- data.frame(column1=column1, column2=column2, column3=column3)

library(lubridate)

# convert to a duration 
c3 <- lubridate::hms(column3)
c3 <- lubridate::duration(hour = hour(c3), minute = minute(c3), 
    second = second(c3))

# convert to numeric to plot
d$c3 <- as.numeric(c3)

# labeling funtion to convert from numeric back to the original 
# format of the duration
yLabels <- function(x)
{
  x <- seconds_to_period(x)
  paste(hour(x),minute(x),second(x), sep = ':')
}

ggplot(d, aes(x=column1, y=c3, fill=column2)) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(),stat="identity") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = yLabels)
```

Comment: Thanks r_alanb. It worked for me. I didnt know about lubridate. I will explore more that library.